# Upper and/lower queriable values jdeveloper

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper

I have a query form in a jspx file and i'm trying to define some of the values as case sensitive, meaning that i want to be able to find, for example, a name with all letters upper case and/or lower case and obtain the values that i would obtain if i've inserted the name correctly.
Can someone indicate me where can i find something to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

--------Update

Code from my jspx file

```
<af:query id="qryId1" headerText="Search" disclosed="true" 
          value="#bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryDescriptor}"
          model="#bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"
          queryListener="#bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}"
          queryOperationListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQueryOperation}"
          resultComponentId="::resId1"
          binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_SearchCustomer.qryId1}"
          maxColumns="3" rows="2" fieldWidth="30%"
          displayMode="compact" saveResultsLayout="never"
          saveQueryMode="hidden" modeChangeVisible="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view criteria, for each criteria item there is a check box `Ignore Case`. Uncheck it if you want to make that search field case sensitive.

If you are using All Queriable Attributes to create your search then you can set it in queryListner method of the query component. Here are the steps:

Create a queryListener method for your query component

`<af:query id="qryId1" headerText="Search" disclosed="true"
                      value="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryDescriptor}"
                      model="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"
                      queryListener="#{backingBeanScope.searchBean.queryListener}"
                      queryOperationListener="#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQueryOperation}"
                      resultComponentId="::resId1"/>`

Make query attributes case insensitive in queryListener method

```
  public void queryListener(QueryEvent queryEvent)
  {
    QueryDescriptor qdesc = (QueryDescriptor) queryEvent.getDescriptor();
    ConjunctionCriterion conCrit = qdesc.getConjunctionCriterion();
    //access the list of search fields
    List<Criterion> criterionList = conCrit.getCriterionList();
    for (Criterion criterion: criterionList)
    {
      ((AttributeCriterion) criterion).setMatchCase(false);
    }
    invokeMethodExpression( "#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}", queryEvent);
  }

  private void invokeMethodExpression(String expr, QueryEvent queryEvent)
  {
    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = fctx.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory eFactory =
      fctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    MethodExpression mexpr =
      eFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, expr, Object.class,
                                      new Class[]
        { QueryEvent.class });
    mexpr.invoke(elContext, new Object[]
        { queryEvent });
  }
```

Comment: Is that also valid when a drag from data controls the all queriable attributes?

Comment: Search panel from all queriable attributes is case sensitive by default

Comment: thk for your replies @amishra.
I have tried to test the query, since you said that case sensitive was active by default, but with no success. Could i be missing something?
I'm adding the query code in my post

Comment: Just to make sure, your search is case insensitive, e.g it gives the same result if you have all letters uppercase or all letters lowercase?

Comment: So, I misunderstood your question, you want to have your search case insensitive such that the cases do not matter. Query by all queriable attributes is sensitive by default. It will not give you any results if you do not put the cases correctly. You then need to use the view criteria and check Ignore Case to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Modified my answer to include the case of creating search by All Queriable Attributes. I think this is what you need